# Solving a system of nonlinear equations using the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, systems-of-equations

After presenting the **Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem**, Zeidler E. (1986) *Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications I - Fixed-Point Theorems*, in p. 53-54, proves that (Proposition 2.8) a system of equations
$$g_i(x)=0, \hskip 10pt \mbox{where } x=(x_1,...,x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^N , i=1,...,N$$
where $g_i$ are continuous functions, has a solution in the closed ball  $\bar{U}(0,R)$ for some fixed radius $R$, if the following condition is satisfied
$$\sum_{i=1}^N g_i(x) x_i \geq 0  \hskip 10pt \mbox{ for all } x \mbox{ such that } ||x||=R.$$

What I don't understand about this is how to "pair" the $g_i$'s with the $x_i$'s in order to take the inner product. Different pairings give different sums for the condition above. Does the condition mean that there exists a pairing of equations with unknowns that is positive, or that all pairings should give a positive inner product, or something else? I also have seen discussions about outward pointing rays and inward pointing rays, but I don't really understand them either.

Also on the same theme, how is this related to the [Poincaré-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) that is also about solutions of non-linear equations (of course, the BFT and the PMT are equivalent). There, each $g_i$ should be paired with the $x_i$ that makes the $g_i$ always negative on $x_i=-1$ and always positive at $x_i=1$. Is there a connection between the two conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indexing of the $g_i$ is a given of the hypothesis for the theorem. I.e., in proving this theorem, you already know this indexing, and have nothing to pair off yourself. However, the result, that there is some $x$ such that all the $g_i(x) = 0$ for all $i$, does not depend on how the functions are indexed. This means in *applying* this theorem to a particular case, you are free to choose an indexing that meets the condition, If there is even one such indexing, it is sufficient for the result to hold.

Comment: The result that $g_i(x)=0$ indeed does not depend on the indexing, but the condition that is sufficient for the existence of such root according to the theorem DOES depend on the idexing since we need to associate an $x_i$ with a particular $g_i$ in order to take the inner product and check the condition. So what you say is that we should check ALL possible pertrubations and if one of them works then the theorem applies. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: No you do not need to "check ALL possible perturbations". Once you find one that works, you can stop looking. Further, by examining the $g_i$, you should be able to work out or at least get a good idea as to which would best be matched with which $x_i$. And more importantly, this whole scenario you propose is one that I suspect is very rare. Normally in applications, $g$ is a given vector-valued function, and you do not have freedom to rearrange its components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand now! Regarding your final comment, you are right if the problem is, say, a physical problem with a clear geometric interpretation, but in economics, my field, such vector-valued functions do come with geometry attached to them. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah - that is why I only said I *suspected* it was rare.  There are always things that I have not personally enountered. Well enough, then.